# Save the Canvas bitmap into storage along with paint. Suggestions?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, storage

So I have coded this app where a user can add a marker on the `ImageView` each time the user clicks the 'Add checkpoint button' **(Look at the screenshots)**. Adding more markers will connect those markers through a line. **The image is scalable, movable and rotatable.**

Now I want to save a copy of the image along with those markers. And the resolution has to be the same as the original. I have the following which does that **but it only saves what is visible to the user. The hidden part is NOT stored.**

This is my function -

```
  private void saveFunction() {

  Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache(true);

  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    Bitmap newBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();*//*
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path + File.separator + "name" + ".png");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        if (!file.exists())

        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        System.out.println("Rushi : saveFunction : saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image: This is when I drag the image out of the screen, only the visible part is stored in my device storage. I don't want that.]

Comment: There's hardly written anything in the official docs. Can you provide me more detail?

Comment: you have to experiment with that

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. I want to give your answer as the correct answer. How do i do that?

Comment: and if you dont want to clip your bitmap with the green markers, i already gave you a solution: just press `S` keycode and setup a breakpoint where `S` kaycode is handled

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Comment: I am getting this error. Even though the 'source' bitmap is initialized in the constructor.

Comment: if `source` is not null, then how come you have `NPE` in `source.getWidth()`? what you see if you set a breakpoint at `Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, [...]`? what is the value of `source`?

Comment: I see the issue now. I have not initialized the constructor itself in my MainActivity. I have added this views XML tag in activity_main.xml. That's why the 'source' is not initialized. What should I do?

Comment: Hello pskink, please check my latest question.